# Function argument in dir function inMATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to use dir command in a function in MATLAB. I want to take argument in fiction and that argument to be part of dir command for e.g

```
function a = abc(num)
    aaa=dir('abc_num_*.csv);
end
```

I am getting error while doing it as num taken as an argument is not going in dir function. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In all programming and scripting laguages I have peeked into, something inside a pair of quotes as in 'quoted' and "also quuoted", has been literal text - to not be changed, ever.

So, you could vager that `'abc_'+str(num)+'_*.csv'` or a similar construct would work for you.
Note that `str(num)` is common as method to convert a numerical value into a stream of characters. Such 'strings' can be appended/prepended to each other with e.g. `+` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use an argument:

```
function a = abc(num)
    aaa = dir(['abc_' num2str(num) '_*.csv']);
    a = aaa.name;
end
```

- Use `[]` to concatenate strings. The wildcard `*` is working.
- Use `num2str` to convert a number into a string.
- Don't forget to check if the `aaa` struct exists before getting its `name` field, for instance by using an `if length(aaa >= 1)` condition.